# Tags: Behavior vs. Psychology

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I recently updated the [psychology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) tag wiki and realized it's really not dissimilar enough from [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior).

What is the difference between these two tags?  How does one determine whether a question belongs in one tag vs. the other tag?

Is it that psychology is mental and behavior is physical?  How does the question asker truly determine which is which?

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use [psychology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) for questions that are "Why is my pet X?".

I tend to use [training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) (or variants like [toilet-training](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training)) for questions that are "How do I change behavior X?"

I tend to use [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) for anything else.

Some examples that I consider "anything else":

- [Do spayed cats still spray?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/do-spayed-cats-still-spray)
- [Is it possible for a deaf kitten to sense growling/hissing from another cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7626/is-it-possible-for-a-deaf-kitten-to-sense-growling-hissing-from-another-cat)
- [Is there a problem with feeding multiple cats from one dish?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7036/is-there-a-problem-with-feeding-multiple-cats-from-one-dish)

In looking over the current useage, I can't see any consistency. However we choose for the tags to be used, the other tags should probably be mentioned in the tag wikis.

Comment: Psychology is a good tag for questions about a behavior that cannot / not intended to be changed.

Answer (score -2):

There are  70 questions tagged [psychology](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology)

There are 394 questions tagged [behavior](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior)

I propose we make psychology a synonym of behavior.

Comment: Then that nakes behavior and even greater catch-all and reduces the utility of the tag. I am wondering if we need to break behaviour down into specific behaviors like incessant barking, paw licking, etcetera

Comment: ["Tags are supposed to organize content to help categorize broad areas of interest"](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/783/should-a-cats-dogs-tag-always-be-added-to-kittens-puppies-questions/787#787)